# How to calculate total cost of BOM of a product in Odoo using a one2many field named 'bom_line_ids'?

Tags: python, odoo

I have created a custom field in the model mrp.BOM structure as below to compute the total cost of BOM for a product:-

```
Field Name:- x_bom_total
Field Label:- Total BOM
Field Type:- Float
ReadOnly:- True
Dependency:- bom_line_ids
```

Dependent Field name 'bom_line_ids' is the field which display all the materials used in the product. It refernces to the model     'mrp.bom.line' in a one2many relationship model. So now in the computation part how to calculate the Total BOM for the product something like this:-

```
for record in self:
    for each_object in record.bom_line_ids: 
        record['x_bom_total'] += record.bom_line_ids.qty * record.bom_line_ids.list_price
```

I am using odoo v11. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right way, but you should consider child BOMs, too.

First your nearly correct approach without child BOMs:

```py
for record in self:
    total = 0.0
    for line in record.bom_line_ids: 
        total += line.product_qty * line.product_id.list_price
    record['x_bom_total'] = total
```

And now with consideration of child BOMs. You're obviously using Odoo Studio App, but i don't know if you can define methods on computed fields, but you can give it a try. A recursive function would be really nice here:

```py
def get_bom_total(lines)
    total = 0.0
    for line in lines:
        if line.child_bom_id:
            total += get_bom_total(line.child_bom_ids)  # recursive call
        else:
            total += line.product_qty * line.product_id.list_price
    return total

for record in self:
    record['x_bom_total'] = get_bom_total(record.bom_line_ids)
```

Comment: Hey @CZoellner I really liked your approach but I am not able to define a function as you suspected in the Compute Field. Can You suggest a better workaround so that I can accept it as an answer. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Also I am not getting the correct price for the product variant.

Comment: How can I get that too.